# What advantage is there in reporting the Lennard-Jones well depth in wavenumber units?

Tags: physical-chemistry, energy, spectroscopy, theoretical-chemistry, units

The Lennard-Jones well depth $\epsilon$ is typically given in energy units ($\mathrm{kJ}$ or $\mathrm{kcal}$; sometimes per mole). Jasper and Miller, however, reported $\epsilon$ values in reciprocal centimeters ($\mathrm{cm^{-1}}$).

Why use $\mathrm{cm^{-1}}$?

1. It seems unnatural using $hc$ as a conversion factor for a classical
   description.
2. Absorption peaks (e.g. in wavenumbers) are not related
   to the LJ potential well, which is for non-bonded interactions.

---

[Ahren W. Jasper, James A. Miller, *Combust. and Flame* **2014,** *161* (1), 101–110.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.combustflame.2013.08.004) ([preprint pdf](http://www.sandia.gov/%7Eajasper/pub/lj.pdf))

Comment: Why not? It's just a conversion factor.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt it seems unnatural using hc as a conversion factor for a classical description.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's any inherent advantage as one can always convert to another unit. It seems natural to me, however, because chemists generally have a good idea of the energy of vibrational and rotatial states in $cm^{-1}$, so being able to compare the depth of the well with some familiar chemical process is quite nice. For instance, if the well-depth were quite small, one could immediately identify that the system may not spend a lot of time there if it is comparable to the zero-point energy or something similar.

It's similar to how physicists report everything in electron-volts ($eV$). They do it because it's familiar and they have many physical processes they can use as a reference. For instance physicists know that the band gap of semiconductors is between $2-5\ eV$, so it's quite natural to report other energies in the same unit.

Comment: are absorption peaks (e.g. in wavenumbers) related to LJ potential well? (LJ is for non-bonded interactions)

Comment: They are related in some sense. Non-covalent interactions absorb light like covalent bonds do. For instance, a water dimer has intermolecular vibrational normal modes, and these normal modes have a certain energy which corresponds to a frequency of light that might be absorbed when using spectroscopy. These modes can only exist because the water molecules are bound in some potential energy well. If I observed one of the modes were at an energy of $1000\ cm^{-1}$, then I know the well must be deeper than that, and I would express the well-depth in $cm^{-1}$.